# Correct Root CA for aswIoT mqtt server

Tags: amazon-web-services, x509certificate, aws-iot

I am using cc3100 wifi chip from TI and I have ported the awsiot sdk for our project. I have one confusion regarding the correct root ca.
I tried these following root ca so far-
RSA 2048 bit key: Amazon Root CA 1.

ECC 256 bit key: Amazon Root CA 3.

RSA 2048 bit key: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary G5 root CA certificate

Cross-signed Amazon Root CA 1

Cross-signed Amazon Root CA 3

These certificates did not work at all. No signer error was coming. Then I was told to use starfield root ca and then I downloaded this one-

Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority from here -
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prepare-for-aws-move-to-its-own-certificate-authority/

This is working. Can anyone explain to me what's the difference between all these roots ca and why this one is working and not the amazon root ca? And, what's the expiry date of this root ca?

Thanks

Akhilesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority-G2 cross-signs amazon root certificates; and Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority cross-signs them again, if the amazon roots CA is not working, one can use the Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority Root CA. I used it and it is working fine.

Useful link- https://searchaws.techtarget.com/definition/Amazon-Trust-Services